# Alarm Clock Settings

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am building an alarm app using **local notifications**. 
I want to add settings inside my app.
So for this I have created the whole view,now I am confused how to store data for multiple alarms?
Whether i should use **NSUserDefaults** or **sqlite**.

Comment: Guess you should split your question on two parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all the choices:

a) Use NSUserDefaults by doing some simple Key amendments like with keys like SettingAttr = Value, e.g. "MyAlarm0Start" = 10:23:12, "MyAlarm1Start" = ... and for instance the number "MyAlarmCount" = 2
or use

b) a complete data model by CoreDate or SqlLite.

I think this strongly depends on how much data you want to store.

Concerning iTunes library am do not understand what you wanted to know.

Edit: Picking things from your media library is handled via the "Media Player Framework", see A[pple Doc IPod Library Access](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/UsingTheiPodLibrary/UsingTheiPodLibrary.html).

Comment: Some Alarm apps outthere are having an options for choosing alarm tones from iTunes music library....
I want to know how this is done...